# SharePoint2013 Search Navigation Web part and query string parameters

Tags: 2013, search-scope, enterprise-search

Im using Search Navigation web part to navigate to a search result page when user decides to do a scoped search. Im trying to pass all scoped search to the same search result page, instead of different search page per scope. When user click's on the item of the Search Navigation, SharePoint passes the search box keyword as query string parameter, which is expected:

```
/searchcenter/results.aspx?k=benefits
```

My question is, how to add another query string parameter that will identify the scope of my search and point to:

```
/searchcenter/results.aspx?k=benefits&q=scope1
```

When I update the Search Navigation item's url to point to:

```
/searchcenter/results.aspx?q=scope1
```

Then SharePoint creates the invalid URL with 2 question marks when user types a search and clicks on the item:

```
/searchcenter/results.aspx?q=scope1?k=benefits
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this same issue. What we did was create a custom handler that knew which URLs to look for then re-route them. For instance, we would have URLs like:

`http://intranet/search/scope1/_layouts/15/handlers/results.ashx?k=query`

The handler reads the URL and knows where to take the token from and then we construct the same JSON object that search would when you use refinement panels.

Like you mentioned, trying any other way to tie another query into Search Navigation hasn't worked for us and resulted in double `?` parameters which won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Scopes are `s=Your%20Scope` and k as you have it is your term.

```
/searchcenter/results.aspx?s=scope1?k=benefits
```

Comment: Eric, i should have not used word "scope". What i meant is, pass a second parameter that will identify something for me, could be either scope, path, property, category etc that will be used as URLToken.ParameterName in the query text of the search web part on the search result page